# Why am I suddenly getting all these review tasks?

Tags: support, review-queue

Over the past two or three weeks, I have noticed an uptick in the number of review tasks open to me (which is pretty cool- it's neat to help out more).  How are review tasks assigned?  Is it based on rep?  Am I suddenly paying more attention?  Or am I only noticing now due to recent changes to the site?

Comment: Are you referring to number of TYPES of review tasks, or of reviewable items within specific type?

Comment: As in, last month I was rarely reviewing anything at all, now I suddenly have review tasks of all types almost daily.

Answer (score 3):

Review tasks are first come first serve. If you have more, it either means you are checking them more, more are generated, or fewer people are working on the queue.

Answer (score 1):

We've also been under a fairly minor troll attack over the past week or two as well; nothing that can't be handled through standard procedures but it does mean that more questions/answers being flagged means more in the review queue.